# How to fire a code behind function when ASP.NET page is completely displayed?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I need to trigger a C# code behind function right after an ASP.NET page is completely displayed.
Is there an event to program?
If not, do how to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by *loads completely*? Loads where? On the client browser?

Comment: I mean After Page is fully displayed on the client browser ..

Answer (score 2):

What you might want to try is [Page Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.enablepagemethods.aspx)/WebMethods. Take a look at the tutorial on [singingeels.com](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx), basically it boils down to:

- Respond to the [Sys.Application.load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383829.aspx) event to trigger a call back to the server to a page method
- Create a page method that contains the logic you wish to execute in response to the call
- Respond to the result sent back from the page method, as appropriate in an `OnSucceeded`/`OnFailed` event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Page_PreRender` event.  This is called just before the `Page` is displayed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I need to fire the function right after the page is fully displayed . Any Idea?

Comment: @Ameno: I would take a look at `jQuery` and use the `$(document).ready(function())`.

Comment: Do you think  that jquery can trigger a C# function?

Comment: @Ameno: Yep! http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1453-call-server-side-function-using-jquery-asp-net.aspx

Comment: Ok I'll give it a try and let you know . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a 'New Web Site' - the default website template comes with an example; the _Default class has the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

There are other events in the [ASP.NET Page Life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) which may be of interest to you. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I need to fire the function right after the page is fully displayed . Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnLoad(e);
   // your code!
}
```

Comment: You have to do this in  InitializeComponent(); section

Comment: Actually I need to trigger the function right after the code is

Comment: Actually I need to trigger the C# function when the page is fully displayed